# linux ps aux command and smem command RSS result is different

Tags: linux

when I use "ps -aux", I can see a process's 'RSS' value is different from the 'smem' command result? what is the difference betweenn the 'RSS' value?

Answer (score 0):

- RSS is the Resident Set Size and is used to show how much memory is
  allocated to that process and is in RAM. It does not include memory
  that is swapped out. It does include memory from shared libraries as
  long as the pages from those libraries are actually in memory. It
  does include all stack and heap memory.
- So if process A has a 500K binary and is linked to 2500K of shared libraries, has 200K of stack/heap allocations of which 100K is actually in memory (rest is swapped), and has only actually loaded 1000K of the shared libraries and 400K of its own binary then:

  `RSS: 400K + 1000K + 100K = 1500K`
- For more information refer this  [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120520221529/http://emilics.com/blog/article/mconsumption.html).
- And for smem refer this [Link](https://www.selenic.com/smem/). It is very useful for information.